# scraping aspx web with python requests - payload parameters don't match

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping, python-requests, invisible-recaptcha

I'm trying to scrape this webpage:https://servicios.sbs.gob.pe/ReporteSituacionPrevisional/Afil_Consulta.aspx

[image]

The total process involves 3 requests, but I'm struggling with first one: [image]

Heres my current code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pypasser import reCaptchaV3, reCaptchaV2
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote

anchor = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6LdR-KUZAAAAANbQ4LKiFpqcLzkNnJ_UanjRRLg0&co=aHR0cHM6Ly9zZXJ2aWNpb3Muc2JzLmdvYi5wZTo0NDM.&hl=en&v=Ya-Cd6PbRI5ktAHEhm9JuKEu&size=invisible&cb=pfvx1zeb6j90'
link = 'https://servicios.sbs.gob.pe/ReporteSituacionPrevisional/Afil_Consulta.aspx'

headers = {
  'authority': 'servicios.sbs.gob.pe',
  'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  #'cookie': 'visid_incap_2355492=k5UhEYBsQ+uJtNXuqL8K+YBXlGUAAAAAQUIPAAAAAADYyxuJseMy0g7445Emml5I; __utmz=197714925.1704243225.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); visid_incap_2391105=KSBMKTQSQn+Bq2oK5mWpNHnllGUAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAC813OvPFqUWRpqxkwnFJ4H; visid_incap_2473956=3bKBek8GT0O8Eq7wRLTnLfUJq2UAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAC2IRyfWwKToPwYbok1THxj; visid_incap_2471123=kRDo/tyPQdCF/0ao5jHxM/sJq2UAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAD3uqNTCrxZYMj6ALoDh0DA; _ga_ZSR8R7PS63=GS1.1.1705708022.1.0.1705708028.0.0.0; __utma=197714925.2059640209.1704220546.1705841954.1706019518.12; _gid=GA1.3.85138041.1706042690; _ga_M92VDMFGFM=GS1.3.1706067248.13.0.1706067248.0.0.0; _ga_XK0K3P9NPZ=GS1.1.1706239969.18.0.1706239969.0.0.0; dtCookie=v_4_srv_1_sn_2848AE6D1A3FBE316E41A9CE816B3987_perc_100000_ol_0_mul_1_app-3A195f854993e4a8e0_0; BIGipServerpool-servicios=856974532.20480.0000; TS013dbf92=019955ae1610604d7d692022dde2408ead730348a058a6ba60c521e6c3d0b31ad62a1a495454e49b8d2d51357d69601759ca6420ff; TS01120b42=019955ae1610604d7d692022dde2408ead730348a058a6ba60c521e6c3d0b31ad62a1a495454e49b8d2d51357d69601759ca6420ff; incap_ses_1722_2473956=HOI9BFCbwDQz8FsG7MXlF50WtWUAAAAA94bs5IP/YF27KaPGpJlZvw==; rxVisitor=17063666217950QGJKAIJQ9IJ2U6PPDBK2V33N42B0J8L; _gat_gtag_UA_39437019_4=1; _ga_C1JCYS9G8B=GS1.1.1706366622.15.1.1706366650.0.0.0; _ga=GA1.1.2059640209.1704220546; rxvt=1706368450791|1706366621810; dtPC=1$566649849_545h-vQGKSMNDJCEPLVOOFUMKGTKARICCSBKSU-0e0; dtLatC=1; dtSa=true%7CC%7C-1%7CBuscar%7C-%7C1706366664242%7C566649849_545%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fservicios.sbs.gob.pe%2FReporteSituacionPrevisional%2FAfil_5FConsulta.aspx%7C%7C%7C%7C',
  'origin': 'https://servicios.sbs.gob.pe',
  'pragma': 'no-cache',
  'referer': 'https://servicios.sbs.gob.pe/ReporteSituacionPrevisional/Afil_Consulta.aspx',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Not A(Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="121", "Chromium";v="121"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

session = requests.Session()

r = session.get(link, headers=headers)
# cookies = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(r.cookies)
# dtcookie = cookies['dtCookie']
recaptcha_response = reCaptchaV3(anchor)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
payload = dict()

payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = "" # soup.select_one("#__EVENTTARGET")['value']
payload['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = "" # soup.select_one("#__EVENTARGUMENT")['value']
payload['__LASTFOCUS'] = "" # soup.select_one("#__LASTFOCUS")['value']
payload['__VIEWSTATE'] = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATE")['value']
# payload['__VIEWSTATE'] = '/wEPDwUJNjk3OTA2NjI2D2QWAmYPZBYCAgMPZBYCAgEPZBYEAgEPZBYGAgEPZBYEAgEPEA8WAh4HQ2hlY2tlZGhkZGRkAgMPEA8WAh8AZ2RkZGQCAw8PFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZBYCAgEPEGRkFgFmZAIFDw8WAh8BZ2RkAgUPZBYCAgEPZBYCAkUPEGRkFgFmZBgBBR5fX0NvbnRyb2xzUmVxdWlyZVBvc3RCYWNrS2V5X18WAwUmY3RsMDAkQ29udGVudFBsYWNlSG9sZGVyMSRSYWRpb0J1dHRvbjEFJmN0bDAwJENvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlcjEkUmFkaW9CdXR0b24xBSZjdGwwMCRDb250ZW50UGxhY2VIb2xkZXIxJFJhZGlvQnV0dG9uMlSualpjUz9kmwVDBnA1wSIfTm7JrORIeQyZh9foGx6F'
payload['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'] = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")['value']
payload['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = soup.select_one("#__EVENTVALIDATION")['value']
# payload['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = '/wEdAAg80F4oOKXO8MwWW8n2gmlt7brr3MWKg9kJViOuirjIB9RwSLIqOtitwuZZJ78DEZKjXH07id5Yjcf4KQeV0GN+2eDC2PVjoIjpEKByAHs6fmVPAap64lWmNhT9mjtZzi+nr1li40HLpyp9vhCN0W5b4WP649c5OmkHuTWa9R5wpY3rZ51n/T0lzw7YPH0QF8p9o2VkDx8hDi0dq6D0NCOY'#soup.select_one("#__EVENTVALIDATION")['value']

payload['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Busx'] = 'RadioButton2'
payload['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtAp_pat'] = 'NARRO'
payload['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtAp_mat'] = 'LEON'
payload['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtPri_nom'] = 'PATROCINIO'
payload['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSeg_nom'] = ''
payload['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnBuscar'] = '  Buscar  '

payload['g-recaptcha-response'] = recaptcha_response

payload_encoded = "&".join([f"{quote(k, safe='')}={quote(v, safe='')}" for k, v in payload.items()])

res = session.post(link, data = payload_encoded, headers = headers)
res
```

First, I used Postman to get the payload and headers, and I got a 'suspicious request' as response in Postman, so the connection was done correctly.

Then, with this I built the previous code, but I get a 404 error in HTML response. I think this is due to `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION` parameters in payload, because if I comment the ones comming from `soup.select_one`, and  instead use the fixes one commented in code (this were my parameetrs tested in Postman) then I get the same response in Postman. So for some reason my `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION` parameters I get in first requests don't seem to correspond with I should get when inspect the webpage.

Any Idea to overcome this? I've tried many hours on this so far but don't make it work.

Comment: The issue is when you hit the page, keep in mind that server side code (c#) runs, sets up some code and variables (like any kind of code does). So, when you hit the page, and that code behind runs? Well, it's going to setup some variables and run some code (values may well not be in viewstate but exist server side. So code behind has to run exactly like if a user hit the page, and in the same order. Posting to a page without first having run the server side code? Then the server side code not going to work. aspx pages are running server side c# code with values that you can't see nor touch.

Comment: so,  you have to let the first page load, then choose the combo box, and then let the page load, and then you can scrape. You can't skip the first landing page, since as noted, that can and will run some server side c# code - code that sets up values etc. like any program does.